# Wordpress: How to prevent auto generation imgs with all possible demnisions

Tags: wordpress, image

Wordpress auto generates images with all possible demnisions..

For example: generate thumbnail, medium, large etc

How I can make wordpress produce images only on demant.
For example if I want only have the thumbnail size for one image, then the only images which are created will be only the original size and the thumbnail size. For other image, maybe I will want only the original kai medium size..

Is it possible to do something like that?
I don't talk about **unset** function..

Sorry for my English!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how WordPress works, it's native behaviour, it generates all possible thumbnails of the image so it can be loaded in any size when needed. In other words, thumbnails are generated when uploading image and not when showing in (*on-demand concept*).